# Using secure https and returning data

Tags: angularjs

I am using a 3rd party API as a booking portal. I am using Angular $http to post to a php curl script on my site that will make the actual call cross site to the API.

```
factory.bookingRequest = function(reservationData){
return $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "api-book.php",
    headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
},
    data: reservationData
    }).then(function(response){
    return response.data;       
});
```

};

**1)**
Does the Angular page that is posting to the php page need to be via https also? Or just the script that is responsible for sending the data outside of the site?

**2)** Also when I get the response back, it has a confirmation number and other details that they have said also need to be via HTTPS.

How would this best be handled? Could I have this as a session cookie and return it to a /booking/confirmation route or return this back to the same page but using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to show confirmation details?

**3)**
Also when I am sending form data from my Angular route to my Php page in the network tab in chrome dev tools I can see all the information that is getting sent to my php page (Request payload in the headers tab). Just wanted to make sure this was ok also?

Comment: Regarding 1) why not sent everything always over https, is the best way to secure your own site. 3) yes, you can see all data

Comment: I agree with @ErikOppedijk. Your page doesn't have to be https if it is the server making the call, but your customers are no doubt sending their personal information to your site, so if it isn't https, it is pointless making an https call to the 3rd party - the info has already been transferred over the internet in plain text

Comment: Do I use the full path to the php script then https mysite/myphppath.com in the Ajax request?

Comment: Thanks  Rhumborl, that's what I was thinking but just wanted clarification